# how to get object length in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to get object length in pure javascript in this code

```js
let myFavGames = {
  "Trinity Universe": {
    publisher: "NIS America",
    price: 40,
  },
  "Titan Quest": {
    publisher: "THQ",
    bestThree: {
      one: "Immortal Throne",
      two: "Ragnarök",
      three: "Atlantis",
    },
    price: 50,
  },
  YS: {
    publisher: "Falcom",
    bestThree: {
      one: "Oath in Felghana",
      two: "Ark Of Napishtim",
      three: "origin",
    },
    price: 40,
  },
};

// Code One => How To Get Object Length ?
let objectLength = ?;
```

Comment: Please explain in your post what you mean when you say "object length", because that's not a thing in JS (objects have no length property). Also, remember to have a look at [all the Object utility functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), because you'll discover a _lot_ of things that you can do with objects.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700/128761) help? (In your case, use `Object.keys(myFavGames).length;`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the number of keys in your object:

```js
const myFavGames = {
  "Trinity Universe": {
    publisher: "NIS America",
    price: 40,
  },
  "Titan Quest": {
    publisher: "THQ",
    bestThree: {
      one: "Immortal Throne",
      two: "Ragnarök",
      three: "Atlantis",
    },
    price: 50,
  },
  YS: {
    publisher: "Falcom",
    bestThree: {
      one: "Oath in Felghana",
      two: "Ark Of Napishtim",
      three: "origin",
    },
    price: 40,
  },
};

const objectLength = Object.keys(myFavGames).length;
console.log(objectLength); // 3
```

Comment: if the answer is a oneliner, good bet the question's a duplicate =)

Answer (score 0):

The **Object.keys()** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names.

`console.log(Object.keys(myFavGames).length);`